# finding the nearest date to the another date column in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, comparison

| epm_vin | repm_milg | repm_ro_dtime | complaints_flag | date_flag | Dates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MALAN51CMBM972380 | 25645 | 2020-10-01 | Yes | Nan | 2021-08-07 |
| MALAN51CMBM972380 | 25845 | 2021-08-06 | Yes | Nan | 2021-08-07 |
| MALPC813MLM018007 | 39305 | 2021-06-12 | Yes | Nan | 2020-10-01 |
| MALPC813MLM018007 | 28795 | 2021-03-05 | Yes | Nan | 2020-10-01 |

```
|   repm_vin         |repm_milg |repm_ro_dtime  |complaints_flag    |date_flag  |Dates|
| :--------      |:-------|:---------|:-----|:----------|:------|:---------|:-----|
|MALAN51CMBM972380  |25845| 2021-08-06| Yes |Yes|   2021-08-07|
|MALPC813MLM018007| 28795|  2021-03-05| Yes|    Yes |2020-10-01|
```

solution should be like above second table means i want the rows where repm_ro_dtime is nearest to Dates column and flag date_flag as Yes.

Comment: `pd.merge_asof` on self may be what you need

Comment: can you explain it further like code and solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
idx = df['repm_ro_dtime'].sub(df['Dates']).dt.days.abs().groupby(df['epm_vin']).idxmin()
df = df.loc[idx].assign(date_flag = 'Yes')
print (df)
             epm_vin  repm_milg repm_ro_dtime complaints_flag date_flag  \
1  MALAN51CMBM972380      25845    2021-08-06             Yes       Yes   
3  MALPC813MLM018007      28795    2021-03-05             Yes       Yes   

       Dates  
1 2021-08-07  
3 2020-10-01
```